# SlackBot with ChatGPT using AWS Serverless APIGatway

Tags: slack-api, openai-api, slack-commands, chat-gpt-4, slack-bot

I am working an chatgpt slackbot using AWS serverless framework. But It's only working on local environment and having slack authentication issue once deployed.

```
[INFO]   Invalid request signature detected (X-Slack-Signature: v0=d6743cdd63f530580f0bd67fdca34f3de75fbac66cbb8932f7ce3abf38f17f6c, X-Slack-Request-Timestamp: 1705430094)
2024-01-16T18:34:54.322Z 15a6b7ac-0b0a-4217-ad06-9e4049f4ed9d INFO [INFO] Invalid request signature detected (X-Slack-Signature: v0=d6743cdd63f530580f0bd67fdca34f3de75fbac66cbb8932f7ce3abf38f17f6c, X-Slack-Request-Timestamp: 1705430094)
```

Does anyone help me to understand what's going on?

Comment: It works fine on local (serverless offline) with ngrok. I distributed the app. but it didn't work.